# Condition for connetedness of a simple Graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If we have $G$ as a simple graph with $n$ vertices and the sum of the degrees of every two vertices, that are not connected through an edge, is at least $n-1$. I have to show, that $G$ is connected.

So my idea was to prove this one indirectly:

If we assume that, $G$ isn´t connected, then there are at least two $v_i,v_j$, such that there is no path between them, from which follows that $d(v_i)+d(v_j)\ge n-1$. Therefore, there should be $v_{i_2}$, such that there is a path between $v_{i_2}$ and $v_j.$

But I am not sure how to continue from this stage and I am not sure whether my approach is correct at all? I would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: If you look at a putative partition of your graph into two connected component, with $k$, and $(n-k)$ vertices respectively what are the maximal degrees of a vertex in the first subgraph, in the second...?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I was thinking about the cardinality the whole time! The degree of a vertex is the number of edges connecting it, and since we have a simple graph, then at most one edge connecting two vertices, then, generally speaking, the maximal degree should be $n-1$, right?

Comment: I would suggest you to draw the situation, if you have a graph with $p$ vertices (connected or not), what is the maximum degree of a vertex? Apply this to each of the two connected components.

Comment: Then it´s $p-1$ or? Am I missing something here, because a vertex could in best case scenario connected to all others with an edge, which means, the maximal degree should be $p-1$ and since it´s simple graph?

Comment: Yes exactly. Therefore, what is the maximal degree of a vertex in the first connected component, and in the second?

Comment: For $V_1$ we would have $k-1$ and for $V_2$: $n-k-1$.

Comment: So you're pretty much done, aren't you? =)

Comment: And if we take $v_1 \in V_1$ and $v_2 \in V_2$, then $deg(v_1)+deg(v_2) \leq (k-1) + (n-k-11) = n-2$, and since we know that $deg(v_1)+deg(v_2) \ge n-1?$ Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108333/discussion-between-ahr-and-variablexyz).

Comment: Inspired by the proof technique that was used in the proof of Ore's theorem
We can prove the claim by using induction on the number of missing edges.

 Base case: we have a graph for which any two no-adjacent vertices have a sum of degree at least as much as $n-1$ and there are no missing edges between vertices. Therefore, it is a complete graph and therefore it is connected.  

Induction step, suppose the claim is true for graph that misses $k$ edges and now consider a graph $G$ that misses $k+1$ edges from being complete and any no adjacent vertices has the sum of degree

Comment: at least as much as $n-1$. Then let's add an edge $(uv)$ to the graph $G$ so that it misses $k$ edges from being complete. 

Now $G+(uv)$ is connected by inductive hypothesis. If the graph remains connected after we have removed the edge $(uv)$ then we are done. Otherwise, the graph $G$ must have two component $u \in A, v \in B$. But if that was the case, $deg(u)+deg(v) \leq n-2$ and we get a contradiction. 

Hope this help!:)